# Usercard expands even if there is less than 28 characters in the About me section

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, user-card

The [privileges page about established users](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/established-user) in Ask Ubuntu reads like this:

> An expanded usercard is only available if you have have at least 28
>   characters in their "About Me" section of their profile.

However, I found a quirky bug today when I noted an usercard of an user expand even when he had 0 characters in his "About me" section.

[image]

It even has a drop shadow effect on the avatar as if the usercard was supposed to expand on mouseover.

[image]

I used this question for checking the bug:

- [How to set the package selection  status to the current status?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166003/how-to-set-the-package-selection-status-to-the-current-status)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That user has 28 characters in the About Me section.

[image: Showing the profile page with blanks selected...sorry for the Windows XP...I apologize sincerely!]

Comment: I knew it. I was about to write this in a comment!